# Scaffolding API controllers are different

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have two Models, `Fish` and `Place`.

**Place:** `Coord` acts as primary key and is set by the user.

```
public Place()

[Required]
public string Coord { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

**Fish:** `FishId` acts as primary key and is set by the DB with identity.

```
public Fish()
{
    Habitats = new HashSet<Habitat>();
}

public int FishId { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Species { get; set; }
```

When I scaffold API controllers for these entities the way the `POST` operation work differ.

**PlacesController:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Place>> PostPlace([FromBody]Place place)
{
    _context.Places.Add(place);
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        if (PlaceExists(place.Coord))
        {
            return Conflict();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return CreatedAtAction("GetPlace", new { id = place.Coord }, place);
}
```

**FishController:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Fish>> PostFish([FromBody]Fish fish)
{
    _context.Fish.Add(fish);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetFish", new { id = fish.FishId }, fish);
}
```

Is it due to the PK not being set by the database that the scaffolded method for `Place` does the extra control for duplicates?

I have also set the `Name` attribute as UNIQUE in the DB so I figure that if EF checks user input for columns that is unique it should probably check for `Name` in the `Fish` model as well?

Comment: If you want to check UNIQUE in model,you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565612/how-to-validate-if-email-attribute-is-unique-in-an-asp-net-core-api).

Comment: Use `[Key]` attribute for the `Coord` property or define it as `Key` when your models are build.